# Create Custom ListView

Tags: custom-list, caml-query, caml, ootb, camlviewfields

Hi guys i have a unique requirement, i have a list of tickets with few columns like Creator name, approver name and signoff names, all are of type "Text" approver name and signoff names can have names of one or more person. i have to create custom view such that all the tickets under particular signoff person should be displayed. 
For example: this is my list.

```
          Createdby                 SignOffs                  Approvers

Ticket1   user1                     signoff1, signoff2        Approver1, Approver2
Ticket2   User2                     signoff1                  Approver1, Approver2
```

i want it to display it like this:

```
          Createdby                 SignOffs                  Approvers

Signoff1

Ticket1   user1                     signoff1, signoff2        Approver1, Approver2
Ticket2   User2                     signoff1                  Approver1, Approver2


Signoff2

Ticket1   user1                     signoff1, signoff2        Approver1, Approver2
```

Also i want it to have all OOTB Features.. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your solution implies showing an item more than one time. OOTB you can't do that. You can make a filter view and show only the signoffs